# ¿Como crear tabla en php?

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando crear un programa que calcule descuentos ya tengo el código pero no entiendo como hacerlo en forma de tabla `k` salga de esta manera intente usar etiquetas `tr` y `td` pero las variables no las detecta.

```
Prod 1   500    100  
Prod 2   300    100  
Prod 3   200    100

Subtotal  
DESCUENTO XX     XX  
TOTAL     XX     XX
```

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
echo"<tr>"
$a=500;
$b=300;
$x=200;    
$desc=0.1;
$desc2=0.05;
$subtotal=$desc * $a;
$subtotall=$desc2 * $b;
</tr>";
</table";

$total;

if($a>500)
{
echo "Se te desconto el 10%";
    echo "El subtotal es " .$subtotal;


    echo "el total es".($a- $subtotal );


}

if($b<500)
{
    echo "Se te desconto el 5%";
    echo "el subtotal es " .($subtotall);
    echo "el total es " .($b - $subtotall);



    }

?>
```

Comment: PROD 1 500 100 <pre>

Comment: Este código presenta muchos problemas: faltan `echo` en algunas partes, 
 en otras hay código HTML suelto sin nada (ni siquiera comillas), se están haciendo (o intentando) asignaciones dentro de `echo`, no hay un bucle o algo que genere un tabla realmente (lo más una fila)... Creo que sería importante que depurases tu código y lo limpiases de errores antes de ver el problema con la tabla. Tal y como está ahora, la tabla no se va a mostrar porque hay varios problemas no relacionados que van a causar errores. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Es estrictamente necesario que imprimas la tabla a través de PHP? Parece que no estás siguiendo el patrón MVC. Sería bueno que trates de guiarte mediante el modelo-vista-controlador te solucionará muchos problemas y te evitara otros tantos. Es una sugerencia. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es la misma estructura de una tabla HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ana</td>
    <td>Ortiz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pedro</td>
    <td>Duarte</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Pero en php, cada elemento o conjunto de elementos se despliega con echo de PHP.

```
$nombre1   = "Adriana";
$apellido1 = "Ortiz";
$arr = array("Pedro", "Duarte");

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "  <th> Nombre  </th>";
echo "  <th> Apellido </th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> " . $nombre1 . "</td>";
echo "<td> " . $apellido1 . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>  <td>" . $arr[0] . "</td> <td>" . $arr[1] ."</td>  </tr>" ;
echo "</table>";
```